# Jsdatepick not passing date data on form submit in firefox or chrome

Tags: javascript, html, forms, asp-classic, input

All inputs pass properly in IE9, and I print them to screen. The inputs for "order" and "progress" are passed correctly in firefox/chrome, but not the "date1" or "date2" fields. They use the jsdatepick library to determine the date - and the date is filled into the form as so: "10-01-2012" . On the next page I pick up the request data and print to screen. Any hints?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsDatePick.full.1.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="jsDatePick_ltr.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"date1",
    });

    new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"date2",
    });
};
</script>
<Form action="ai_school_stats_return.asp" method="POST" name="stats">
  <input type="hidden" id="order" name="order" value="order">
  <tr>
    <td width="40" align="right">From date:</td>
    <td align="left"><input type="bundatetext" name="date1" id="date1" maxlength="10" value=<%=Session("date1")%>></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40" align="right">To date:</td>
    <td width="60"><input type="bundatetext" name="date2" id="date2" maxlength="10" value=<%=Session("date2")%>></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40" align="right">Lesson Progressed Past</td>
    <td width="60"><input type="text" name="progress" id="progress" maxlength="10" value=<%=Session("progress")%>></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="183">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="133">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="184">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <div align="center"><input type="image" value="submit" src="../images/submit_up.gif" width="132" height="30"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</Form>
```

Comment: what is input type="bundatetext" ?

Comment: It is the type they used in the jsdatepick example, I never heard of it either - I have already tried "text" and "date" as well.

Comment: it should be "text". show how you get the values in ai_school_stats_return.asp

Comment: On ai_school_stats_return.asp I've tried both Request("date1") and Request.form("date1") depending on whether I was using GET or POST

Comment: also tried Request.QueryString("date1") when using Get

Comment: I have tried your code and it does work for me. If your remove the <%=Session("date1")%> there, is there any difference ? also try hard coding some values there as value="test_date_here"

Comment: okay, found an extra comma here: target:"date1", in the script part. remove that too.                                           new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"date1"
    });

Comment: good eye catching those commas. I tried removing the session value and hardcoded a value - it autopopulated the field with that value fine but still on submit it didn't actually pass it. Surprisingly not in the URL when I use GET: ai_school_stats_return.asp?order=order&progress=3&x=64&y=14 - so you tried it and it worked on firefox?

Comment: yes, it did work for me. Are you still using the same code as you have shown in the question ?

Comment: and what is x and y ? the hard coded values ?

Comment: The x and y confused the heck out of me. They appeared when I started using GET- and are random values changing on each run! IE has them too along with the correct data - so they aren't hurting anything. This is very helpful to know that the above code works for you - likely another script/code library is conflicting on the page. Also I'm using ASP classic rather than just html so it points to a problem outside of the above code. I'll let you know after I do more testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be something extremely simple. I had a table declared outside of the form. So firefox saw the table containing the inputs outside the form while figuring out what data to pass- which when combined with the .js fn it ended up passing data not involved in the fn. Lesson: You know something is really wrong with your code when IE works but firefox doesn't.